# Creating EdgeShapeFunctions

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to understand how to write a custom [`EdgeShapeFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeShapeFunction.html). What is not clear in the documentation is what the function uses as input. The example given is

```
ef[pts_List,e_]:=Block[{s=0.15,g=graphic},{Arrowheads[{s,.03,g},{s,0.67,g}],Arrow[pts]}]
```

My question is **"What is the list `pts` and what is `e`?"**

Is `e` the edge list and `pts` the coordinates of the vertices?

Comment: The edges are lines defined by a list of two points. The  function `ef` changes each `Line` into an `Arrow` using each line's points and using the `Arrowheads` specification.